# Multiple errors when attempting to add MoPub adverts

Tags: java, android, eclipse, mopub

I am attempting to switch from my current admob advertising to using mopub. I *think* I followed the instructions correctly on the mopub website, but clearly I must have done something wrong. I've put a screen grab from eclipse [here](http://www.fullreservebanking.com/goof.png) to show the problems. Any idea what I've done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like eclipse can't find android 4 for the MoPub sdk- have you downloaded the latest Android versions with your Android SDK manager? I think if you download 4.0.3 & recompile everything, things should be resolved.

EDIT (from @Geobits)
You need API version 4, which is Android 1.6. You can download this from your Android SDK manager.

Comment: API version 4, which is 1.6. Make sure you have that SDK downloaded, as some people don't bother going back that far.